# Doctrine: Relacionamento ManyToMany com Campos Extras

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, relacionamento, doctrine-2

Tenho um relacionamento muitos para muitos entre duas tabelas: Produtos e Pedidos.

O Doctrine gera então uma terceira tabela. Até aí tranquilo.

Porém queria gerar nesta terceira tabela mais campos (qtde e valor unitário no momento da compra).

**A pergunta é:** Como faço esse relacionamento funcionar no Doctrine (com as annotations direto nas Entidades) e como faço para pegar/setar depois a quantidade e o valor de um determinado produto do pedido (terceira tabela)?

O mais perto de uma explicação que achei foi isso: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616157/doctrine-2-and-many-to-many-link-table-with-an-extra-field/15630665#15630665

Mas ali não é explicado o funcionamento do ArrayCollection para casos assim e nem como fazer para pegar ou setar os campos extras da terceira tabela.

Desde já agradeço toda ajuda que puderem dar.

**Tabela Products** *(Tabela 1)*

```
Id           (pk)
Name
Value
```

**Tabela Orders** *(Tabela 2)*

```
Id           (pk)
TotalValue
```

**Tabela ProductsOrders** *(Tabela de Instersecção)*

```
Product      (fk)
Order        (fk)
Quantity
UnityValue
```

--

**Entidades**

Segue abaixo as entidades feitas conforme instruções. Note, porém, que falta o método correto de se trabalhar com as colunas extras - i. e., como fazer para e **EntityManager** pegar as colunas extras da entidade **ProductOrder** (através, claro, dos campos de ligação nas entidades **Product** e **Order**).

Também é importante a informação de como proceder para fazer o relacionamento desta terceira tabela com uma outra, já que ela não possui ID prórpio, posto que o ID é formado pelo conjunto de ID do Produto + ID do Pedido.

```
<?php

/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="Repositories\ProductRepository")
 * @Table(name="Products")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Column(length=100)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2)
     */
    protected $value;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductOrder", mappedBy="product")
     */
    protected $orders;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->orders = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId(int $id): Product
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): Product
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getValue(): float
    {
        return $this->value;
    }

    public function setValue(float $value): Product
    {
        $this->value = $value;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getOrders()
    {
        return $this->orders;
    }

    public function addOrder(Order $order)
    {
        if ($this->getOrders()->contains($order)) {
            return $this;
        }

        $this->getOrders()->add($order);
        $order->addProduct($this);

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeOrder(Order $order)
    {
        if (!$this->getOrders()->contains($order)) {
            return $this;
        }

        $this->getOrders()->removeElement($order);
        $order->removeProduct($this);

        return $this;
    }
}

/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="Repositories\OrderRepository")
 * @Table(name="Orders")
 */
class Order
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2)
     */
    protected $totalValue;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductOrder", mappedBy="order")
     */
    protected $products;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->products = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId(int $id): Order
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getTotalValue(): float
    {
        return $this->totalValue;
    }

    public function setTotalValue(float $totalValue): Order
    {
        $this->totalValue = $totalValue;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getProducts()
    {
        return $this->products;
    }

    public function addProduct(Product $product)
    {
        if ($this->getProducts()->contains($product)) {
            return $this;
        }

        $this->getProducts()->add($product);
        $product->addOrder($this);

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeProduct(Product $product)
    {
        if (!$this->getProducts()->contains($product)) {
            return $this;
        }

        $this->getProducts()->removeElement($product);
        $product->removeOrder($this);

        return $this;
    }
}

/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="Repositories\ProductOrderRepository")
 * @Table(name="ProductsOrders")
 */
class ProductOrder
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Order", inversedBy="products")
     * @JoinColumn(name="order", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $order;

    /**
     * @Id
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="orders")
     * @JoinColumn(name="product", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $product;

    /**
     * @Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $quantity;

    /**
     * @Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2)
     */
    protected $unityValue;

    public function getOrder()
    {
        return $this->order;
    }

    public function setOrder($order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->product;
    }

    public function setProduct($product)
    {
        $this->product = $product;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getQuantity()
    {
        return $this->quantity;
    }

    public function setQuantity($quantity)
    {
        $this->quantity = $quantity;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getUnityValue()
    {
        return $this->unityValue;
    }

    public function setUnityValue($unityValue)
    {
        $this->unityValue = $unityValue;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Exemplo de uso da EM**

```
<?php

$product = $em->getReference(User::class, 1);
$order = $em->getReference(User::class, 1);

$productOrder = new ProductOrder();
$productOrder
    ->setOrder($order)
    ->setProduct($product)
    ->setQuantity(5)
    ->setUnityValue(99.9);

// Isso está cadastrando corretamente.
$em->getRepository(ProductOrder::class)->create($productOrder);

// Porém, isso não está funcionando:
echo $order->getProducts()[0]->getQuantity();
```

Comment: Poderia postar seus models? O que a resposta linkada sugere é que seja criada uma terceira entidade, algo como um `OrderItems`

Comment: A terceira tabela não eh orderitens. A terceira tabela (ou como ela deve ficar) eh a ProductsOrders. Já que eu posto as entidades como estão no momento.

Comment: Para facilitar minha necessidade, adicionei como estou fazendo no momento. Note que o cadastro funciona (embora acredito que posa ser feito de outro jeito) porém não encontrei uma forma de, pela entidade Order pegar os dados extras dos produtos do pedido (como quantidade comprada, por exemplo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer é tratar a terceira tabela (**PorductsOrders**) como um entidade normal.

Neste caso você não usará ArrayCollections (pelo menos não nas entidades) e fará as pesquisas usando apenas a tabela de intersecção.

Para isso remova a opção *InversedBy* das anotations da entidade **ProductOrder** e remova as propriedades Store#products e Product#stores.

```
/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="Repositories\ProductOrderRepository")
 * @Table(name="ProductsOrders")
 */
class ProductOrder
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Order")
     * @JoinColumn(name="order", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $order;

    /**
     * @Id
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product")
     * @JoinColumn(name="product", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $product;

    /**
     * @Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $quantity;

    /**
     * @Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2)
     */
    protected $unityValue;

    public function getOrder()
    {
        return $this->order;
    }

    public function setOrder($order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->product;
    }

    public function setProduct($product)
    {
        $this->product = $product;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getQuantity()
    {
        return $this->quantity;
    }

    public function setQuantity($quantity)
    {
        $this->quantity = $quantity;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getUnityValue()
    {
        return $this->unityValue;
    }

    public function setUnityValue($unityValue)
    {
        $this->unityValue = $unityValue;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Você pode fazer uso da entidade de intersecção assim:

```
<?php

$product = $em->getReference(User::class, 1);
$order = $em->getReference(User::class, 1);

$productOrder = new ProductOrder();
$productOrder
    ->setOrder($order)
    ->setProduct($product)
    ->setQuantity(5)
    ->setUnityValue(99.9);

// Isso está cadastrando corretamente.
$em->getRepository(ProductOrder::class)->create($productOrder);
```

Para pesquisar, pode ser feito assim:

```
<?php 

// Pesquisando:
$productOrder = $em->findBy([
    'order' => 1,
    'product' => 1
]);
```

**Obs**: Opcionalmente, em seu repositório **ProductOrderRepository**, você pode criar o método `findByIds($orderId, $productId)`, o método `findOrderProducts($orderId)` e o método `findProductOrders($productId)`

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Segundo esse [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542243/doctrine2-best-way-to-handle-many-to-many-with-extra-columns-in-reference-table) a solução é considerar a tabela de join como uma entidade separada e mapear os relacionamentos como One-To-Many.

Na implementação que mostrastes o mapeamento de `Product.orders` e `Orders.product` já deve retornar uma lista de `ProductOrders`, assim já tens acesso às colunas extra.

Vais precisar acrescentar um constructor em `ProductOrders` que receba o `Product` e o `Order`:

```
ProductOrder{ 
    ...
    public function __construct(Order $order, Product $product, $quantity= 0, $unitValue=0) 
    { 
        $this->product= $product; 
        $this->order= $order; 
        $this->quantity= $quantity; 
        $this->unitValue= $unitValue; 
    } 
}
```

Podes também acrescentar os `getters` e `setters` da mesma maneira que fizeste nas outras entidades.

Comment: Agradeço a disposição, porém a necessidade está principalmente acessar os campos extras pela EntityManager. Note também que é solicitado a melhor maneira de se fazer uso das ArrayCollections para este caso nas entidades Product#orders e Order#products

Comment: @Szag-Ot Sendo que `ProductOrder` é mapeado como uma entidade tu vais utilizar o EM(EntityManager) da mesma forma que faria para fazer uma query de `Product` ou `Order`. Com relação ao `ArrayCollections` não ficou claro qual é a dúvida.

Comment: Product e Order possuem ID. Já em ProductOrder, o ID é um conjunto de ambas entidades. Como fazer um $em->find()? Uma forma seria usar o $em->findBy() passando ambos os ids, mas isso não me parece ser o certo. Também, ao usar a entidade Product ou a Order para pegar a coleção da contra-tabela, os campos extras não são trazidos. (Exemplo: $orders->getProducts() retorna a lista de entidades Produto relacionadas ao pedido, porém SEM OS CAMPOS EXTRAS). Perceba o pq necessito de uma resposta bem completa....

Comment: para faciliar minha necessidade, adicionei como estou fazendo no momento. Note que o cadastro funciona (embora acredito que posa ser feito de outro jeito) porém não encontrei uma forma de, pela entidade Order pegar os dados extras dos produtos do pedido (como quantidade comprada, por exemplo)